# MVC4 pass client side info to action to download file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC4: I used to use @Url.Action to call Controller's Action that would return FileContentResult  (file),  to download that file to client's system. Now I need to pass client side data (id-s of selected by client items) to the same Controller's Action to use when generating file-to-download.
But Url.Action can't pass data generated on client side, AJAX call will not work also. 
How to do that ?

Comment: Why won't AJAX work?  It knows about client side data.  That's kind of the point :)

Comment: How did you try to pass your data? You can use querystring as GET request or you can POST your data.

Comment: You either pass them within a query string (that should work with an ActionLink) or with a post (or other) method, like within a form or an ajax call. Ajax *should* be working fine...